# Album Images Not Showing Up When Called From Spotify API Android Studio

Tags: android, spotify

I am trying to have the album images for each of the top tracks shown next to their song but no matter what I do they are showing up as little green boxes.

[image: Photo of What's Happening]
Here is the relevant code:

```
public void onGetUserProfileClicked() {
    if (mAccessToken == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You need to get an access token first!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Create a request to get the user profile
    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + mAccessToken)
            .build();

    cancelCall();
    mCall = mOkHttpClient.newCall(request);

    mCall.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d("HTTP", "Failed to fetch data: " + e);

        }

        @Override

        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.d(TAG, "JSON Response: " + jsonResponse);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
                JSONArray itemsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

                StringBuilder formattedData = new StringBuilder();

                // Add header for top tracks
                formattedData.append("<h2>Your top tracks!</h2>");

                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject trackObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject albumObject = trackObject.getJSONObject("album");
                    JSONArray imagesArray = albumObject.getJSONArray("images");
                    String imageUrl = "";
                    if (imagesArray.length() > 0) {
                        JSONObject imageObject = imagesArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        imageUrl = imageObject.getString("url");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Image URL for track " + i + ": " + imageUrl);
                    }

                    String artistName = "";
                    JSONArray artistsArray = trackObject.getJSONArray("artists");
                    if (artistsArray.length() > 0) {
                        JSONObject artistObject = artistsArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        artistName = artistObject.getString("name");
                    }

                    String trackName = trackObject.getString("name");

                    // Load image using Glide
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(imageUrl)
                            .into(imageView);

                    // Create HTML content for each song box
                    formattedData.append("<div style=\"display:flex; align-items:center;\">")
                            .append("<div style=\"width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-right: 10px;\">")
                            .append(imageView)
                            .append("</div>")
                            .append("<div style=\"border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;\">")
                            .append("<p>").append(trackName).append(" - ").append(artistName).append("</p>")
                            .append("</div>")
                            .append("</div>");
                }

                // Display the formatted data with HTML formatting
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    profileTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedData.toString(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
                    profileTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                });
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error processing response: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to process response",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            }
        }

    });
}
```

When I logged the image urls in my logcat to see if theyre valid, they were as when I clicked on them they showed up fine on the internet and I made sure my androidmanifest.xml allowed internet usage.